Inconsistent usage of static/stack/heap memory
I've been messing around with assembly for a while and I found things which seems inconsistent. After some research I have some questions about stack / static (initialized/uninitialized) / heap memory.
First of all, does memory freed out of the heap, becomes available for other processes? Sometimes I hear that heap only limitation is RAM memory limit, but then it must mean that unused memory is available for other processes. Meanwhile custom malloc implementation just initialize heap of some size, which definitely reserve this space, not letting other programs use it.
Second of all, I've created once a float variable in C and compile it to assembly. One of the results was the label with .long property/parameter (not sure about gcc assembly) and number after it being equal to decimal value of IEEE 754 representation of the value I chose. So, I guess it's the same as the static allocation (so it uses memory in the whole lifespan of runtime). But then, it allocated the value from this label on the stack. Weird I guess...
After all of these I just wander, when is static allocation (outside of global variables) is good for "variables which at the first look shouldn't be allocated statically".
I've watched some videos and searched for my questions but I didn't find an answer. A few experiments in NASM assembly with floating-point put me here.

Modern OSes use virtual memory, so unmapped parts of a process's address-space aren't using RAM.  Real-world malloc implementations give memory back to the OS when its freed (e.g. with munmap), only keeping some smaller blocks on a free list that's still (as far as the OS is concerned) allocated by the process.  So small mallocs can be satisfied without making a system call, larger allocations will need an mmap / VirtualAlloc. (Same for smaller allocations if the free list is exhausted).

it allocated the value from this label on the stack - I have no idea what you mean.  Perhaps you mean it reserved stack space and copied from .rodata to that stack space?  Yeah, compilers often use static storage for FP constants, including initializers for locals in automatic storage when they don't get optimized away.  For x86, a 32-bit immediate could work equally well, but traditionally that's not how compilers handle FP constants.

.LC0: .long ... and stack allocation
movss .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
movss %xmm0, -4(%rbp) These 3 dots are my number

Though you didn't post the C code (which would have been informative), it appears that your snippet has a local (float) variable that is initialized.  The floating point constant value (...) has to come from somewhere, so here the compiler put it in static (probably .rodata).  The initialized variable never lived in the static data, only the initializing value lives there.  Then the variable itself, located on the stack, is initialized from the constant value in static data.  There are other ways to obtain constants; probably because of the exact value, the compiler choose static data as best.

@ErikEidt in this case I just wrote the simplest code possible to show it, anyways here it is:
int main(){ float a = 0.5; }
I do understand why compiler did it, but I just wander if it isn't memory waste as it stays for the whole runtime. Also, you are right, it's in rodata:
[...] .LFE0: .size main, .-main \n .section .rodata \n .align 4 .LC0: .long 1056964608 [...]

Yes, there's some cost in memory usage, though other alternatives would also occupy some memory.  For example, using (perhaps multiple) code instructions, whose size would perhaps equate to similar cost in memory usage.  In any case, consider for function other than main; one that could be invoked many times during the life of the program — then that static data is being reused upon each invocation of that function.

@ErikEidt Thank you very much! I would also ask you why are integers or strings allocated on stack then but my guess is that putting/loading integers on/from stack is cheaper than floats. As long as they are not going to be reused, of course. Again, tysm!

Constants tend to go into the static data, constants like string literals.  However, some variables need to be mutable and have the lifetime associated with their scope.  In your example, a is instantiated and initialized each time the function is called; it is mutable such that the function can modify its value while the variable exists.  So, we need to differentiate between values and variables, i.e. between constants and potentially mutable items — and if you get into optimization, between mutable variables that are actually modified and those only used for their initial value.

You didn't enable optimization so there's no reason to expect efficiency.  If you did enable optimization for that example, float a would just optimize away.  Modifying the example to pass the address of a to another function (whose definition the compiler can't see), the compiler is forced to materialize a in memory.  https://godbolt.org/z/qdTj5Wcrq shows GCC, Clang, and MSVC doing that with a mov-immediate (mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 0x3f000000).  If you used a in a way that the compiler could constant-propagate, it wouldn't copy to stack space. (@ErikEidt)

Near duplicate - Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?
